# CS50 IDE problem(An unexpected error happened.)

Tags: c, ide, cs50

I am trying to open my CS50 ide. I got this error after singing from my GITHUB account.
Do you get this error ever.

**An unexpected error happened. Try reloading the page. Email b87502bc-137f-4c5e-9315-1ee0fe1f3e24 to sysadmins@cs50.harvard.edu if the problem persists!**

My CS50 ide is opening like this.
I Emailed the error to system admin. Let's see...

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not allowed by the owner to get inside it. I get the same error when i try it and actually if you try connecting to some of my courses in my university page u will get kind of the same error.